# How to pass ajax call result to subsequent ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im currently trying to utilize multiple ajax calls through ajax chaining, but unsure on the best approach since there are a few ways to do this via new frameworks, jquery and pure javascript.

I would prefer to do this with pure vanilla javascript given the native development on js has improved a lot over recent years, however, in the instance of multiple ajax calls, i believe there is still plenty to be improved upon, i believe one of the ways would be to use promises ? i do see many deal with this occurrence via jquery.

i would be very appreciative if fellow coders could give their example as to how they would code a modern approach ajax chain call dependent on ajax returned call values preceding it.

ok, so in short, i am attempting to pass the value of the first ajax call to the second ajax call, along with identifying the correct way of executing the second ajax call.

Below i have added code with comments:

```
// Establish functionality on window load:
window.onload = function() {

    'use strict';

    // get product id on load
    var pid = document.getElementById('pid');
    var colorlist = document.getElementById('colorlist');
    var sizelist = document.getElementById('sizelist');

     colorlist.onclick = function(e) { 
    if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;

    var colorid = e.target.value

    while (sizelist.firstChild) {
    sizelist.removeChild(sizelist.firstChild);
    }

        // 2ND AJAX CALL
        var xhr = getXMLHttpRequestObject();

        xhr.open('GET', '/ajax/get_sizes.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(pid.value) + '&colorid=' + encodeURIComponent(colorid), true);
        // set header if sending to php
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send(null);

        // Function to be called when the readyState changes:
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            // Check the readyState property:
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

                    // Check the status code:
                    if ( (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) 
                    || (xhr.status == 304) ) {

                    var sizes = xhr.responseText;
                    var sizes = JSON.parse(sizes);

                    for (var i = 0, num = sizes.length; i < num; i++) {

                    var label = document.createElement('label');

                    label.setAttribute ("for", sizes[i].id);
                    label.classList.add("swatch");
                    label.innerHTML = sizes[i].size;

                    var radio = document.createElement('input');

                    radio.type = "radio";
                    radio.id = sizes[i].id;
                    radio.value = sizes[i].id;
                    radio.name = "sizes";

                    sizelist.appendChild(label);
                    sizelist.appendChild(radio);

                    } //END OF FOR LOOP

                } else { // Status error!
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = xhr.statusText;
                }

            } // End of readyState IF.

        }; // End of onreadystatechange anonymous function.
    }; // END OF COLORLIST ONCLICK

    // 1ST AJAX CALL
    var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();

        // Function to be called when the readyState changes:
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

            // Check the readyState property:
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {

                // Check the status code:
                if ( (ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 300) 
                || (ajax.status == 304) ) {

                    var colors = ajax.responseText;
                    var colors = JSON.parse(colors);

                    for (var i = 0, num = colors.length; i < num; i++) {

                        var label = document.createElement('label');
                        label.setAttribute ("for", colors[i].id);
                        label.classList.add("swatch", colors[i].color);
                        label.innerHTML = colors[i].color;

                        var radio = document.createElement('input');

                        radio.type = "radio";
                        radio.id = colors[i].id;
                        radio.value = colors[i].id;
                        radio.name = "colors";

                        colorlist.appendChild(label);
                        colorlist.appendChild(radio);
                    } // END OF FOR LOOP

                } //END OF STATUS CODE CHECK
                    else { // Status error!
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ajax.statusText;
                    }

            } // End of onreadyState IF.

        }; // End of onreadystatechange anonymous function.

    ajax.open('GET', '/ajax/get_colors.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(pid.value), true);
    // set header if sending to php
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.send(null); 

}; // End of onload anonymous function.
```

Regards David

Comment: Add the second function as a callback from the first. Yet if the second one relies totally on the outcome of the first without any futher input from the user, you could just put it all in one call (usually).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO and thank you for your question. I'll do my best to show you some examples of how you could execute your code in a way that might be preferable to you as a solution.

## Callbacks

What is a callback?

> Simply put: A callback is a function that is to be executed after another function has finished executing — hence the name ‘call back’.

[Source of quote](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced)

In your code example you want to execute at least 2 HTTP request after one another. This would mean that a piece of code has to be executed twice. For this you can write a function around the `XMLHTTPRequest` piece to be able to execute it multiple times when writing it down only once.

The function below here has two parameters: `url` and `callback`. The `url` parameter is a string which will be injected in the second parameter of the `xhr.open` method. The `callback` parameter will be a function. This function will be called when the request has been succesfully finished.

```
function get(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      if ('function' === typeof callback) {
        callback(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url, true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send();
}
```

Here is a little example of how it would work. See that the callback function has a parameter called `data1`. That is the `xhr.responseText` that we got back from the `XMLHTTPRequest`. Inside the callback function call the `get` function again to make another request.

```
get('/ajax1.php', function(data1) {
  // Do something with data1.

  get('/ajax2.php', function(data2) {
    // Do something with data2.
  });

});
```

This is a fairly simple way to make a request after another is finished.
But what if we have 100 requests after each other?

## Promisified XMLHTTPRequest

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

[Source of quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Enter Promises. The example below here is almost the same as the example above. Only this time we use a `Promise`. When calling `get` we immediately return a `Promise`. This promise will wait for itself to either `resolve` or `reject`. In this case we only use `resolve` for successful requests. Whenever the request has finished `resolve` is called and the *Promise chain* begins.

```
function get(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        if ('function' === typeof callback) {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url, true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

So instead of using a *callback function* we use `then`. Inside `then` we do use a *callback function* which allows us to use the value that has been *resolved* in the returned `Promise`. `then` can be chained with more `then`'s inifinitely until you run out of things to chain.

Inside the callback function call the next request.

```
get('/ajax1.php')
  .then(data1 => {
    // Do something with data1.
    get('/ajax2.php')
      .then(data2 => {
        // Do something with data2.
      });
  });
```

## Fetch

> The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used XMLHttpRequest, but the new API provides a more powerful and flexible feature set.

[Source of quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Before we've created our own `Promise` version of an XMLHTTPRequest. But JavaScript has evolved an has gotten new tools to work with. `fetch` kind of looks like how our `get` function works, but has way more features and options to make it more powerful. And it also uses *promises*!

```
fetch('/ajax1.php')
  .then(response1 => response1.text())
  .then(data1 => {
    // Do something with data1.

    fetch('/ajax2.php')
      .then(response2 => response2.text())
      .then(data2 => {
        // Do something with data2.
      });

  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Though the `then` syntax still makes us nest functions. Like before, what about when you have 100 callback functions to call? That will be a nesting mess!

## Fetch + Async/Await

Now this is the way to tackle the *nesting problem* and make the syntax more like assigning a simple variable in JS. **Async/Await** is a part of modern JavaScript, so be wary of older browsers not supporting it. Check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions) for the current support.

The **Async/Await** syntax works like the following. Create a function with the `async` keyword in front of it. This will indicate, like it implies, that *async* code will be performed here. It also makes the function with async before it automatically return a `Promise`.

Inside the *async function* use the `await` keyword whenever you call a function which returns a `Promise`, like `fetch`, or our own function `get`. This will return the **resolved** value without having to use `then` or a callback function.

The `await` keyword also makes the code actually *wait* before continueing to the next line of code. Now your JS looks nice and can be written with less nesting.

```
(async function() {

  const response1 = await fetch('/ajax1.php');
  const data1 = await response1.text();
  // Do something with data1.

  const response2 = await fetch('/ajax2.php');
  const data2 = await response2.text();
  // Do something with data1.

}());
```

I really hope this is helpful and helps you get where you need to be going.
If you have any questions regarding the above, please let me know!

Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise chain which could be like the example mentioned below:

```
.then(function(result) {
    return doSomethingElse(result);
    })
    .then(function(newResult) {
    return doThirdThing(newResult);
    })
    .then(function(finalResult) {
    console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
    })
    .catch(failureCallback);enter code here
```

You can the documentation mentioned below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises